# Reduce the spaces between the column in flex column chart

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

In flex how to reduce the spaces between the column in column chart.my columnWidth Ratio is 0.4  without changing this ratio how to reduce the spaces between the column?

Thanks,
AravuindakumarThangaraju

Answer (score 0):

do you mean paddingLeft and paddingRight?